# Upload PDF file From iOS app to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, pdf

I am trying to upload a PDF from an IOS app to Facebook. I first started using 
`SLComposeViewController` but I found that I can only post text via `setInitialText` and images via `addImage, so I begin trying to use faFcebook api from https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ and the sample code for the API:

1 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/
 2 https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

None of them show or indicate how to upload file PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot post a PDF file to Facebook. 
What you can do is to upload the PDF file to your server and post a link to the PDF file on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

[ASIHttpRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) can be used to upload file via http.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];

NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath: file_path ];

if ( data != nil )
{
    [request setData:data forKey:@"file"];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: but how iam going  to use ASIFormDataRequest to upload this file on Facebook ,u cant just put facebook url in the request ,i must use facebook API's